# Frozen/Incorrect 'Date Created' and 'Date Modified' in Finder

Tags: finder, high-sierra

The `'Date Modified'` and `'Date Created'` are completely wrong in the Finder. Not off by a Time-Zone adjustment, just plain wrong. For instance, I created new directories today at 14:01 and they appear as `Apr 23, 2018 at 12:06` and other such incorrect dates. The `Date Added` attribute is correct.

[image]

I noticed this today and it looks like it started happening a couple of days ago, perhaps 4 days ago at most. I think that's around the time I applied the updates below. **Any suggestions?**

MacBook Pro, macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 Update, Version installed Apr 3, 2018.
Security Update 2018-001, Version installed Apr 26, 2018.